# Unable to set style for html in the actual style sheet

Tags: html, css

I am trying to utilize the new CSS3 functionality to create a background for my page that scales with the browser window.

The style works fine when I include it directly in my html doc, but that is ugly and clutters my workspace, something I DONT want to do.

I have tried to include it in my stylesheet, but it merely doesnt appear. Other elements of the CSS sheet work just fine

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Relevant HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US" class="no-js" 
style="background: url(assets/placeholder_one.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
 background-size: cover;"
 >
<head class>
    <!-- To be changed ASAP -->
    <title>####</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/logo_1.ico">

    <meta name="author" content="Noah Litov">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="#####">   

    <!-- My styles and bootstrap -->
    <link href="styles/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

And my CSS doc (login.css)

```
.no-js { 
    background: url(assets/placeholder_one.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You code is okay, i think problem is with your path.

Comment: Style for `HTML` or `BODY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check assets/placeholder_one.jpg is accessible in that path you have specified. login.css is in styles directory and image in assets. Try to change the path to ../assets/placeholder_one.jpg.

Comment: That solved it. Its funny, I was sure that the directory would be fine since assets is a subfolder

Answer (score 0):

write your css like

```
  .no-js { 
background: url(assets/placeholder_one.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

It will be better if you write your css as follows

```
body{
     background: url(assets/placeholder_one.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Still not functioning. Is it possible its Notepad++?